# HttpClient returns The server committed a protocol violation - Browser returns correct data

Tags: c#, webclient

I am trying to setup github with membership reboot.

If I try calling the github api from a browser like

> https://api.github.com/user?access_token=XXXXXXX

I can see all the valid json data however if I try from .net

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var url = "https://api.github.com/user?access_token=XXXXXXXX";
        ////add additional params
        //if (additionalParams != null)
        //{
        //    foreach (string key in additionalParams)
        //    {
        //        url += string.Format("&{0}={1}", key, additionalParams[key]);
        //    }
        //}

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var result =  client.GetAsync(url).Result;
        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var json =  result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            var profile = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
            //return GetClaimsFromProfile(profile);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

I get an error of

> The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine

What doesn't HttpClient like about what I am trying? Do I need to provide extra details that the browser is doing for me?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked at the final url?  Could there be a newline or illegal character?

Comment: The final url looks good, For the example above I changed the url to be a hardcoded string but thats the actual value from the code

Comment: What's the actual value?  You didn't give a value for `additionalParams`, and I suspect the problem is caused by the values it contains

Answer (score 2):

Adding

```
<system.net>
    <settings>
      <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true" />
    </settings>
  </system.net>
```

to my web.config seems to solve the problem...I dont really understand why I needed to add this but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is relevant here, but I got the same issue on the https://api.github.com/user endpoint. My solution was simpler than I thought, but nevertheless annoying as it took me several hours to find out.

The `User-Agent` should be passed to the API Endpoint, maybe it works here also by specifying a `User-Agent`.